# Google Sheets: Return a single value from array using multiple criteria

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I provide different services for my job, but my rates vary from client to client, I'd like a formula to get the rate value (0.04, in this case) using two values, the name of the client "Client 3" and the service in question "Service 2".

I have created a spreadsheet to better illustrate what I am trying to accomplish, hopefully someone can help.

Rates tab.

| Client | Service 1 | Service 2 | Service 3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Client 1 | 0.06 | 0.02 | 0.08 |
| Client 2 | 0.07 | 0.03 | 0.09 |
| Client 3 | 0.08 | 0.04 | 0.1 |
| Client 4 | 0.09 | 0.05 | 0.11 |
| Client 5 | 0.1 | 0.06 | 0.12 |
| Client 6 | 0.11 | 0.07 | 0.13 |
| Client 7 | 0.12 | 0.08 | 0.14 |
| Client 8 | 0.13 | 0.09 | 0.15 |
| Client 9 | 0.14 | 0.1 | 0.16 |
| Client 10 | 0.15 | 0.11 | 0.17 |

Sheet `1` where results go

| Project name | Client 3 | Service 2 | {formula here}0.04 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |

[Link of the example sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1_GXhOq4QWxDXdSvCHr3k0BlRxtfWM45QkyN7SolXLxY/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: `QUERY()` will do nicely in that case.

Comment: @Hi david, welcome to stackoverflow, make sure to see this [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to make a selfe contained question.

Comment: Kindly add input table and expected output table as [**plain text table**](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/161855/) to the question. Adding such "markdown tables" greatly increases your chances of getting a elegant answer. If you share spreadsheets, your question maybe closed, as questions here must be [self](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260455) [contained](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/149892). [Your email address can also be accessed by the public](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/394304/), when you share Google files.

Comment: The votes doesn't reflect the quality of the answers because All the formulas responses [works as expected](https://i.imgur.com/ICpvH6G.png)

Comment: @David-mota-robles [This](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/73934426/timeline#history_2381e39c-7c88-4a74-ba76-7a2a4f0774ba) is how you should ask your next question, and on top, include your research and failed approach to benefit future visitors for months and years to come.

Answer (score 1):

This works regardless of how many **clients** or **services** you have.

```
=MAP(B1:B,C1:C, LAMBDA(c,s, 
 IFERROR(INDEX(Rates!B2:D, MATCH(c,Rates!A2:A,0), MATCH (s,Rates!$B$1:1,0)),"")))
```

[image]

**Demo**

[image]

Used formulas help
[**`MAP`**](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/12568985) - [**`LAMBDA`**](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/12508718) - [**`IFERROR`**](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093304) - [**`INDEX`**](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098242) - [**`MATCH`**](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093378)

Answer (score 0):

Use `vlookup()` and `match()`. Put this formula in cell `1!D1`:

`=arrayformula( iferror( vlookup(B1:B, Rates!A2:D, match(C1:C, Rates!A1:D1, 0), false) ) )`

The formula will fill the whole column in one go.

Answer (score -1):

use:

```
=INDEX(VLOOKUP(B1&C1, SPLIT(FLATTEN(Rates!A2:A&Rates!B1:E1&"×"&Rates!B2:E), "×"), 2, ))
```

[image]

or arrayformula of it:

```
=INDEX(IFNA(VLOOKUP(B1:B&C1:C, 
 SPLIT(FLATTEN(Rates!A2:A&Rates!B1:E1&"×"&Rates!B2:E), "×"), 2, )))
```